# Create Sqlite Table with a Column having Autocalculation

Tags: android-sqlite

I m using below code for creating SQLite table.

```
db.execSQL("Create table if not exists " + datausage + "(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, mainentry text, stime integer , endtime integer, usedtime integer)");
```

But I want usedtime should autocalculate when I insert stime and etime. usedtime will be difference of etime and stime.

so can we create a column which do calculation automatically. I got this for sql as stated below.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Products
   (
      ProductID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
      , QtyAvailable smallint
      , UnitPrice money
      , InventoryValue AS QtyAvailable * UnitPrice
    )
;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017

but this does not work in case of SQLite and I m getting invalid sql statement
can we do this ?

Comment: SQLite does not support computed columns. What you can do is create triggers for insert and update that will update the column.

Comment: oh. it means I have to manually handle it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> But I want usedtime should autocalculate when I insert stime and
>   etime.

Assuming that you mean **endtime** rather than etime. Then you can add a [TRIGGER](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) that will automatically **UPDATE** the usedtime **AFTER** the row has been **INSERT**ed.

e.g.

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS datausage_timedifference AFTER INSERT ON datausage
    BEGIN
        UPDATE datausage SET usedtime = endtime - stime WHERE id = new.id;
    END
;
```

## Example

Consider the following demonstration:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS datausage;
Create table if not exists datausage (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, mainentry text, stime integer , endtime integer, usedtime integer);
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS datausage_timedifference AFTER INSERT ON datausage
    BEGIN
        UPDATE datausage SET usedtime = endtime - stime WHERE id = new.id;
    END
;
INSERT INTO datausage VALUES (null,'mainentry1',10,30,0),(null,'mainentry2',50,75,0);
SELECT *, endtime - stime AS alternative_usedtime FROM datausage;
```

This will :-

- drop the table (for ease of rerunning/adjusting, you wouldn't do this normally)
- create the table
- create the trigger named **datausage_timedifference** that will automatically update the **usedtime** after a row is inserted.
- add some rows where the usedtime is 0
- select the rows from the table showing that usedtime has been automatically calculated

The result being :-

[image]

***Note*** that the above also shows that there is no real need to store a value that is derived from other values, as this can be calculated when extracting the value from the database as per

```
endtime - stime AS alternative_usedtime
```

*This generates an extra column in the result set (Cursor) called **alternative_usedtime** that is the difference between **stime** and **endtime**. As such the usedtime column isn't required.*

*Deriving a value in this way also does away with the potential need for a second AFTER UPDATE trigger to handle any changes made to the stime or endtime columns.*